# How to implement interface into application class?

Tags: android, interface

I have this application:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private AppInterface appInterface;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        appInterface = (AppInterface) this;
    }

    public void something() {
        appInterface.result();
    }
}
```

Using this interface:

```
public interface AppInterface {
    void result();
}
```

And I am trying to call some method inside app and get result from interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppInterface {

    @Override
    public void result() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final App app = (App) getApplication();
        app.something();
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

*E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.something, PID: 13803
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.something.App: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.something.App cannot be cast to com.something.AppInterface
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5406)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.msd.test.App cannot be cast to com.msd.test.AppInterface*

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: First, calling `getApplicationContext()` inside an `Application` is pointless. Just use `this`. Second, `App` *contains* an `AppInterface` instance. `App` itself is not an `AppInterface` instance.

Comment: Ok, replace getApplicationContext() by "this" is clear, but how to fix it? Can you show me?

Answer (score 6):

Try Interface as following :

In App.java :

```
    public class App extends Application {

        private AppInterface appInterface;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }

        public void something(AppInterface appInterface) {
            this.appInterface = appInterface;


//save this for future use, and whenver you want to pass data , use this method like-
        appInterface.result();
    }
}
```

In MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppInterface {

    @Override
    public void result() {
      Log.d("result", "called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final App app = (App) getApplication();
        // pass you reference from here
        app.something(MainActivity.this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see my mistake :)

Comment: Hey @Michalsx you should mark this answer right, So other can also get their answer if they also get this issue..

Comment: To all, I marked answer as right, you should see that :)